# Autopep8 not breaking long comment lines?

Tags: python, pep8

I tried using autopep8 to format some python code, expecting that comment lines above 80 characters would be split up, among other things. I used this test file `test.py`, which only consists of comments:

```
#asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
#asdf asdf asdf asdf
#asdf asdf asdf asdf

#asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
#asdf asdf asdf asdf
#asdf asdf asdf asdf
#asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
```

I then ran `autopep8 test.py`

This gives the following output:

```
# asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
# asdf asdf asdf asdf
# asdf asdf asdf asdf

# asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
# asdf asdf asdf asdf
# asdf asdf asdf asdf
# asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
# asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
```

The last long line is split, but the first two aren't.  I think all the lines should be broken at 80 characters wide.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6, autopep8 0.9.7, and pep8 1.4.6 on OS X 10.8.5.  I get the same results on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

autopep8 doesn't automatically fix all long lines; it only does it in cases where it's deemed 'safe'. See:
https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues/39